# Ubuntu 18.04 on Acer Spin 5 with \EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi not found

Tags: boot, live-usb, debug

I attempted to reinstall Ubuntu 18.04.1 on my Acer Spin 5.

Installation appeared to go fine, but then when I restarted:

```
Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi - Not Found
Failed to load image \EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi: Not Found
Failed to start MokManager: Not Found 
Something has gone seriously wrong: import_mok_state() failed
: Not Found
```

For context:

I was running Ubuntu 18.04.1 on my Acer with an 8 GB swap partition for a while with no issues - had originally installed using a bootable USB with ISO disc file.

I got all my files off the hard drive and put the USB in - booted from it and attempted to install by selecting normal installation, opted to erase Ubuntu 18.04.1 and reinstall - I've included a picture of what happens when I attempt to restart: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fg98L.jpg (same output as above)

How can I approach fixing this bug?

Answer (score 1):

## Solution:

Enter BIOS and ensure Secure Boot is disabled. I then performed the following actions:

1. Select Security
2. Select "Erase Secure Boot settings"
3. Select "Restore Secure Boot to factory default"
4. Press F10 (restart)
5. Enter BIOS
6. Select Security
7. Select "Select UEFI file as trusted for executing"
8. Select "HDD0", select "EFI", select "ubuntu", select "grubx64.efi", name it "grubx64efi", press Enter key twice
9. Disable Secure Boot (I did not adjust my load-order in any way before disabling Secure Boot)
10. Press F10

Everything booted up just fine.

Here are two resources for further references. Cheers to Niclas Borlin and jacobbrett for solving this problem.

- [[SOLVED] Unable to boot to ubuntu from an SSD](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2391280&p=13764703#post13764703)
- [System fails to boot with \EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi - Not Found - Linux Mint Forums](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1570832#p1570832)

Answer (score 0):

The problem obviously starts when the loader cannot find `\EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi`.

Can you boot from Ubuntu live CD or USB and check the content of the partition that was mounted to `\EFI\BOOT`? I am guessing `/dev/sda1`. If there is another .efi file there (`grubx64.efi` being the primary suspect), you could try to copy or rename it to `mmx64.efi` and reboot.

See: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1798171, https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/ooooy-efi-boot-mmx64-efi-efi-not-found-4175644607/.

Comment: Niclas, thank you very much for your answer. I'm an Ubuntu novice and a Linux beginner...I don't know how to check the content of any partitions in Ubuntu...do you know any resources that explain how to do that? thank you

Comment: We need more info about the partition. Do the following to list the content of the EFI partition:
 1. Boot into a live CD/USB.
 2. Open a terminal window (Ctrl-Alt-T).
 3. Create mount point with `sudo mkdir /tmp/sda1`.
 4. Mount as read-only with `sudo mount -o ro /dev/sda1 /tmp/sda1`.
 5. Check content of partition with `ls /tmp/sda1`. If you get `EFI` as the printout, you have the right partition.
 6. Run `tree --charset unicode /tmp/sda1` and paste the result here.

Comment: Niclas - sorry it has taken me so long to get back to you. Naturally, PC still doesn't work. I recently tried a couple of other solutions to no avail. I followed your instructions using Mint terminal but i'm assuming that's no big deal. 

printout screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/Z2H35oq

pasted: 


tmp/sda1
`-- EFI
    |-- BOOT
    |   |-- BOOTX64.EFI
    |   `-- fbx64.efi
    `-- ubuntu
        |-- BOOTX64.CSV
        |-- fw
        |-- fwupx64.efi
        |-- grub.cfg
        |-- grubx64.efi
        |-- mmx64.efi
        `-- shimx64.efi

4 directories, 8 files